# How can i format Text in python like i would in Illustrator?

Tags: python, latex, typesetting

I am looking to achieve several features to sweeten up the output of my program. 
I want to set the background of a column of text to a certain color so that it is 
more clear that columns belong together.

A picture is worth a thousand words:
i want to convert this:

```
Pos.  :123456789012345
Name. :ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO  
Str.  :SOMESTRINGSOMET  <---- indented by half a row, Column number superscripted
Str.  :SOM       SOMET
Str.  :SOMESTRIN    ET
```

to this:

[image: example]

How can i do that using python ? Is there a framework that alows me to do this?
I converted this into latex, however i cannot get the superscripted numbers to work. They need to be above the text, but not acting as a character, since there is a relation between the columns of the picure.

> Example: A is at position 1. It has as Properties S and O, thats why it is on top of those two and that is why there is an indent of half a character. S has the superscript 170, T has the superscript 185.

particularly hard is also the part where the Str part is shifted by half a character.I would like to have an example for this to integrate into my program.

Comment: Outputting to LaTeX or some other typesetting/formatting tool seems like the way to go. Python doesn't come with a typesetting library.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. i made the "right" grafic with illustrator. however i just cant get that stuff to work even with latex right now :( will update once i get a step further.

Comment: Is this question restricted to mono spaced fonts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to come up with tricky solutions, considering mono spaced fonts, that may solve your problem. But they are just waiting to fail. The gray columns in your post can be added exactly as in your figure, but I've chosen to not make it change the colors in the letters (simply because I find it more readable this way).

Here is something possible to come up with PIL:

[image]

Slightly changing the fonts:

[image]

More "severe" font changes next, all produced with the code as is.

[image]    [image]

And next is the code for generating these figures. I didn't really make it nice, and it can be improved in many ways. Consider this as an example of what you will need to do to, maybe, achieve a solution for your problem. To work with any kind of font you will need an actual typesetting system, such as LaTeX.

```
import sys
import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont


# Assumption: some other piece of code separates the data in the following
# format.
line1 = [("Pos.  :", 0), ("123456789012345", 0)]
line2 = [("Name. :", 0), ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO", 0)]
line3 = [("Str.  ", 0), (":", -0.5), ("SOMESTRINGSOMEST", -0.5)]
line4 = [("Wave 1:", 0), ("_XXXX_X____X_X_", 0)]
line5 = [("Wave 2:", 0), ("__XX_XXX_X__X_X", 0)]
line_data = [line1, line2, line3, line4, line5]
# Texts to draw over the last element, in specific positions,
# of lines present in line_data.
subscript = {
        2: { # Meaning: third item in line_data
            0: "170",  # Meaning: draw "170" over the first char
            len(line3[-1][0]) - 1: "185", # Draw "185" over the last char
            7: "180",   # Meaning: draw "180" over the eight char
           },
        4: {5: "hi"},
        3: {6: "ops"}
        }

# If the following fonts are not mono spaced, you are going to suffer.
#
# Normal font.
font = ImageFont.truetype('FreeMono.ttf', 40)
# Font for subscript.
font_tiny = ImageFont.truetype('FreeMono.ttf', 20)


im = Image.new("RGBA", (1000, 1000), 'white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
line_offset = 4
start_y = 6

width_A, height_A = font.getsize('A')
_, height_tiny_A = font_tiny.getsize('A')

# Collect even columns from the last item of list line1.
even_columns = []
x = 0
for i, (text, _) in enumerate(line1):
    for j, letter in enumerate(text):
        if i == len(line1) - 1 and not j % 2:
            even_columns.append(x)
        x += width_A

# Write all lines.
width = 0
l_start_y = start_y
for di, data in enumerate(line_data):
    x = 0
    for i, (text, xoff) in enumerate(data):
        for j, letter in enumerate(text):
            # Apply x offset.
            extra = width_A * xoff
            draw.text((x + extra, l_start_y), letter, font=font, fill='black')
            x += width_A
    width = max(x, width)
    l_start_y += height_A + line_offset

# Collect letter positions from the lines that will have subscripts.
letter_pos = {}
for k in subscript:
    letter_pos[k] = {}
    x = sum(len(text) for text, _ in line_data[k][:-1]) * width_A
    text, xoff = line_data[k][-1]
    for i in range(len(text)):
        extra = width_A * xoff
        letter_pos[k][i] = x + extra
        x += width_A
# Write all subscripts.
for k, v in subscript.items():
    line = line_data[k]
    for pos, text in v.items():
        x = letter_pos[k][pos]
        y = start_y + (line_offset + height_A) * k
        y -= height_tiny_A * 0.4 # XXX A poor heuristic that worked here.
        draw.text((x, y), text, font=font_tiny, fill='black')
        width = max(width, int(x + font_tiny.getsize(text)[0]))

# Draw grey columns.
columns = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, 'white')
mask = Image.new("L", im.size, 'white')
for x in even_columns:
    columns.paste((128, 128, 128), (x, line_offset, x + width_A, l_start_y))
    mask.paste(164, (x, line_offset, x + width_A, l_start_y), )
im = Image.composite(im, columns, mask)

# Crop and save the resulting image.
im.crop((0, 0, width, l_start_y + 2)).save(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: awesomeness. exactly what i was looking for. What if i wanted to add more lines like Str underneath? would i just change 'for di, data in enumerate([line1, line2]):' to for di, data in enumerate([line1, line2, linex]): ?

Comment: Yes, that would work. But you also need to adjust the drawing at `for k, v in line3_1_top.iteritems(): ...`. I would start by adding a `num_lines = x` where `x` is the total number of lines you wrote, like 4 in your case and 3 in my example. And change the code for drawing the subscripts for handling that.

Comment: actually i dont need to repeat that. I just want to add some more lines below in the same manner as str. Your code is a level above my skill :-). I will award the bounty once i got that to work. I also want to repeat the line_3_1 bit every 10 characters or so, like column numbers

Comment: If you want to simply add more lines below the initial 3, then you will have to repeat this code for the next lines. This could be turned into a function. The `dict` line3_1_top indicates the character position as the key and its subscript as the value, so you can simply add 11: "180" to it and it will work in this case. If we are in agreement on what you want to perform, I could try updating the code so it is a little more flexible on drawing other sets of strings below each other.

Comment: basically what i have is a long version of this: http://postimage.org/image/khuserq8v/

Comment: See the updated answer, the code is more manageable and should be easy to change to match your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a LaTeX question than a Python question -- i.e., if you determine the markup that you want your Python script to generate, then actually generating it is fairly easy.

In this case, I think you could probably get the effects you want with a fairly complex table (`\begin{table}...\end{table}`), where each of your cells spans two columns, and one column is used as the offset to get the "half character" you want.  It wouldn't surprise me if there's an easier way to do this in LaTeX (which has way more libraries than I can keep in my head), but that's the one that comes to mind.  So your table would look something like this:

```
+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| pos. |  |  1  |  2  |  3  |      ... 
+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| name.|  |  A  |  B  |  C  |      ... 
+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|      | 170 |     |     |     |   ... 
+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
| Str. |  S  |  O  |  M  |  E  |   ... 
+------+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

(Where `+`s indicate where the actual columns are, and most cells span two columns.  The row with "170" on it would use `\tiny` or some such command.)

My suggestion would be to play around with generating a LaTeX file by hand first that does what you want (or some other formatting language of your choice file); and then worry about writing some python code to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

While PIL works ok for simple stuff, you have a lot more options if you use SVG.  You can use [pySVG](http://codeboje.de/pysvg/) (handy [pySVG tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/pysvg/source/browse/trunk/pySVG/src/tests/pySVGTutorial.py?r=8)) or svgwrite  to create your SVG programmatically, or just `print` it as text.  Then use ImageMagick (either on the commandline as `convert` or from python using [pythonmagicwand](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/pythonmagickwand)) to render the SVG to any raster type you want.  While fine tuning the SVG you can edit it with a text editor and look at it in a web browser :)

```
# make some text in any font, any size, any effects
import pysvg
s = svg()
myStyle = StyleBuilder()
myStyle.setFontFamily(fontfamily="Verdana")
myStyle.setFontSize("5em")
myStyle.setFilling("blue")
t1 = text("Hello World", 0, 100)
t1.set_style(myStyle.getStyle())
s.addElement(t1)
s.save('test.svg')

from pythonmagickwand.image import Image
img = Image('test.svg')
img.format = 'PNG'
img.save('test.png')
```